# Tapping on register at the same time from two device creates two users

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, serverless-architecture

I am working on a backend code where while registering users, we check device ID, mobile number everything is repeating or not.

My QA just found the issue that if we tap on register users at the same time from two different devices with same details except for the email ID, then it registers both users.

**I am checking if the user already exists or not in the very first line of code but response time is greater than the difference in taps on two mobiles.**

I checked that the difference in two users created timestamp is 260ms.

**We are using node.js + AWS + GraphQL**

```
const register = async (mobile, name, etc)=> {
     let result = await findOne('users', {mobile: mobile}) // returns true/false
     if result throw error
     else register
}
```

Happy to provide any other required information. Unfortunately, I will not be able to provide any other code samples.

Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: no matter - confirmation will pass for only one?

Comment: hi.. as he is tapping both at the same time, both are going in for registering and once they are in, they both get register. Only one will be accessible at the end though.